# Difference between Heroku db and local db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have some weird behaviour in my Heroku database. When I submit a form in my Rails app locally, it gets stored alright:

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "gamerounds" ("created_at", "end_date", "number", "period_id", "processed", "start_date", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 03 Jan 2014 09:18:26 CET +01:00], ["end_date", Wed, 02 Mar 2011 00:00:00 CET +01:00], ["number", 46], ["period_id", 3], ["processed", false], ["start_date", Sat, 02 Apr 2011 00:00:00 CEST +02:00], ["updated_at", Fri, 03 Jan 2014 09:18:26 CET +01:00]]
(0.3ms)  COMMIT
```

When I do the same on the Heroku app (same code, same database), I get this error:

```
Started POST "/gamerounds" for 77.250.108.220 at 2014-01-03 08:15:05 +0000
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "gamerounds" does not exist at character 13
INSERT INTO "gamerounds" ("created_at", "end_date", "number", "period_id", "processed", "start_date", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"):
app/controllers/clubs_frenzy/gamerounds_controller.rb:22:in `create'
```

When I create a Postgres dataclip with `select * from gamerounds;` on Heroku, it just returns the table with records without a problem. I restored the local database on Heroku, so they are exactly the same. If both the code and the database are the same, what can be the problem?

Comment: @Jhon post your create method code

Comment: seems like you didn't migrate your Heroku database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the following commands

```
heroku run rake db:reset
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku restart
```

Comment: Will I not lose all data when I do this?

Comment: then leave the first command, execute migrate and restart commands